# Vue Event from Parent (App.vue) To Another Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-events

I would like to emit an event from `App.vue` which is a main component to another component.
`EventBus.$emit` from App.vue, `EventBus.$on` on child/another component is not working.
Since there is no child relation directly between these, I cannot use `@custom-event=""` either

How can I throw an event from `App.vue` to another component?

That's what I do. It is working all of the other components. Here my components' folder structure

```
-src
-pages
  -main-page
    -MainPage.vue  $on
-event
-constant
-store
-router
App.vue  --> $emit
main.js
```

Comment: How is it not working for you, can you elaborate a bit more? Also, your sentence `Since there is no child relation directly between these` doesn't make sense since EventBus works independently, you just need to make sure it imports from the right source.

Comment: Look at the event bus method of passing events described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940012/1030527 You can use it to send events to parents or child components

Comment: EventBus is not working as well as I mentioned, imports checked. If I use EventBus in other components except App.vue, it is working. However, in App.vue which is the  top of element or page whatever you call in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the EventBus method isn't working but it should be so I'll assume you're doing it wrong. Do something like this:

Create `eventBus.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

In any of your single file components, import it:

```js
import { EventBus } from '/src/path/to/eventBus.js';
```

Trigger an event in a component:

```js
EventBus.$emit('some-event-raised', { someData: "bob" })
```

In any other component, do the import again and then listen:

```js
EventBus.$on('some-event-raised', obj => {
  console.log(`some-event-raised triggered [${obj.someData}]`)
});
```

Comment: That's what I do. It is working all of the other components. I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: How about is you emit / listen using `this.$root.emit()` / `this.$root.on()`? I can't remember if this is part of the default Vue stuff or just in the Quasar framework I use (you should check it out BTW, handles a lot of things like this for you)