Vue JS 3 Integration With Vaadin Events
I am integrating VueJS 3 With Vaadin (as I want to avoid Lit) but I am experiencing issues with 2 aspects:
First: it seems vaadin checks the vue files syntax and doesnt like it so I dont know how to bypass that.
Secondly: I am not able to emit or dispatch events from Vue and capture them from Vaadin with @DomEvent annotations (I am saying this as I tried with VueJS 2). Is there any way ?.
For instance:
@DomEvent("custom-name")
public class ClickEvent extends ComponentEvent<CustomView> {
    public ClickEvent(CustomView source,
                      boolean fromClient,
                      @EventData("event.name") String eventName,
                      @EventData("name") String name
                      ) {
        super(source, fromClient);
    }

}

The VueJS Component would lkook like:
<script>
    export default {
        name: "custom-view",
        template: "<button @click='fireEvent'> Fire Event</button>",
        methods: {
            fireEvent: function(){
    
                    var evt = new Event("custom-name");
                    evt.name = "Agustin";
                    this.$emit(evt);
    
            }
        }
    }
</script>


I don't know about Vue syntax about dispatching events, but at least you should use CustomEvent instead of Event. You might need to set the composed and bubbles properties to true if your element has a shadow root. Additionally, you should use the detail object to store any custom payload. In plain JavaScript, it would look something like this:
   const event = new CustomEvent('custom-name', {
     detail: { name: 'your custom name' }, bubbles: true, composed: true
   });
   this.dispatchEvent(event); // 'this' is a reference to the element root


Hi ! Thankx for your answer... Did you meant sonething like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993508/vuejs-bubbling-custom-events
